# Which planes are most receptive to nonnative land ownership?

Tags: planescape

I'm planning to GM a *GURPS 4e* campaign using the Planescape setting.

One player wants his character to be a really rich royal vampire. He wants the character to own land on multiple planes. If it were only Sigil or the Outlands, that wouldn't be a problem, but how does land ownership work on the planes when everything is about the Powers and their Philosophies?

Which planes allow nonnatives to own land and rule an area, even if the nonnative isn't devoted to any particular power or philosophy?

Comment: Step 1 of running a campaign in a setting you're not familiar with: Read up on the setting. Read everything you can get your hands on so you at the very least know the setting basics. Even better would be to know a a lot, or even close to most things.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I took a crack at editing this. Feel free to roll it back if it no longer jibes with your intent. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: Also, which GURPS supplements will you be using? That's kinda important to know with GURPS.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs This isn't really a question *about* GURPS. I've actually removed the tag, as the question contains no GURPS problems.

Comment: This question is Too Broad for an entertaining reason: The *planes* are too broad. Quite literally, most individual planes are so freakin' huge and diverse in content that they won't have a single set of laws and customs regarding land ownership over their full breadth and width.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sigil does not have the nobility you'd see on the Prime. The closest to a queen it has is Her Serenity, the Lady of Pain. But she does not rule, instead she just is. Titles of nobility do exist, but they are inherited from the Prime. An example of this would be Duke Rowan Darkwood, Factol of the Fated. The closest Sigil has to actual nobility are the merchant princes, certain priests, Faction leaders and all others who have either made their own fortune or inherited.

Do remember that the Planes are infinite in size, and therefore land is essentialy worthless. I don't know how GURPS handles rules for owning and profiting from land, but you'd need a damn good reason as to why you are established across the Planes.

However, there's an option. Go pick up Planescape Monstrous Compendium II and look for the Merkhants in there. They're a Sect (a mini-Faction) that are all about owning money-making enterprises and gaining power through wealth. They don't own land, they own businesses. They blend in this way, acting as respectable merchants until they pretty much own everything in a burg. They do work interplanar: they can own cattle on Ysgard, ships on the River Oceanus, contacts on Mechanus and arms deals with the Yugoloth. A Merkhant's hoard is largely non-liquid, but this doesn't hamper its size or worth.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd so so far as to say it's _worthless_. That's ignoring the boon of proximity. Even if infinite, not all locations are equally accessible; owning a mine two days from Heart's Faith in Lunia is going to be naturally more valuable than owning one two months away, or two years away, for example. And while some planes do have natural qualities or characteristics that can subvert travel time concerns - e.g., Mechanus's Labyrinthine Portal or Elysium's Traveler's Way - these aren't present on all planes, especially those for which hard work is a major theme.

Comment: Thanks, this really give me an idea of how to handle it. I figured it couldn't be land based as planescape really is huge and i really couldn't think of a reason for some vampire count to rule over planars and petitioners in lieu of powers or proxies or people of their own faith.

Comment: @Jckunz Note that there's a lot of land in the planes that isn't part of a divine realm. The Outlands is the classic example - a lot of it is just countryside (or wilderness) that independent bashers have claimed and settled, but the other outer planes are much the same; If you look at any plane's map you'll see that the divine realms are only a small part of the total area. There's no reason why an enterprising basher couldn't set himself up as jarl of a Ysgardian earthberg, or establish a hermitage on a lunian island off the coast of Celestia, or buy the mining rights of a patch of Baator...